# How to get all child components of QWidget in pyside/pyqt/qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, children

I am developing a desktop application using pyside(qt), I want to access(iterate) all line edit components of QWidget. In qt I found two methods *findChild* and *findChildren* but there is no proper example found and My code shows error, *'form' object has no attribute 'findChild'.*
Here 'form' is Qwidget form consist components lineEdit, comboboxes, Qpushbuttons etc.

Code:

```
lineEdits = form.findChild<QLineEdit>() //This is not working

lineEdits = form.findChild('QLineEdit) //This also not working
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The signatures of `findChild` and `findChildren` are different in PySide/PyQt4 because there is no real equivalent to the C++ cast syntax in Python.

Instead, you have to pass a type (or `tuple` of types) as the first argument, and an optional string as the second argument (for matching the `objectName`).

So your example should look something like this:

```
lineEdits = form.findChildren(QtGui.QLineEdit)
```

Note that `findChild` and `findChildren` are methods of `QObject` - so if your form does not have them, it cannot be a `QWidget` (because all widgets inherit `QObject`).

Comment: @ekhumoro could you please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164853/how-to-use-findchildren#25165738

Answer (score -4):

Use this method [QObject::findChildren(onst QString & name = QString())](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) with no parameters.

> Omitting the name argument causes all object names to be matched.

Here is C++ example code:

```
QList<QLineEdit*> line_edits = form.findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
```