# How to use findChildren?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I want to click a button and clear around 20 QLineEdits.

I am trying to use findChildren() and put all the QLineEdit in a QListWidget

```
self.StudentAdmissionLayout = QGridLayout()
self.StudentAdmissionLayout.addWidget(self.StudentName,1,0,1,1)
```

The self.StudentAdmissionLayout layout has all the QLineEdit placed on it.

```
self.myList = QListWidget()
self.Item = QListWidgetItem()
self.Item = self.StudentAdmissionLayout.findChildren(QLineEdit)
self.myList.addItem(self.Item)
```

I am getting below error:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QListWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
QListWidget.addItem(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

I am trying to put the above 4 lines in a loop. But the 3rd line isn't working, I am not sure how to make it work.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please give more information. I don't know what is this ??? 'self.StudentAdmissionLayout'. What is type ?

Comment: @Kitsune Meyoko : 'self.StudentAdmissionLayout' has all the QLineEdit placed on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, we have to understand behavior of `list-of-QObject QObject.findChildren (self, type type, QString name = QString())` . The documentation for this class says

> Returns all children of this object with the given name that can be
> cast to type T, or an empty list if there are no such objects.
> Omitting the name argument causes all object names to be matched. The
> search is performed recursively.

**Source**: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#findChildren

Then, it returns a Python `list` to you and each element in the list is type of T (the type you provided as input). So your problem:

> ```
> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> QListWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
> QListWidget.addItem(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
> ```

is because you pass a list, but `addItem` requires a `QListWidgetItem` or `QString` (or Python `str`). If you want to pass a Python `list` you must use a `for` loop to iterate over the data:

```py
myQListWidget = QListWidget()
listsItem = ['my', 'data', 'are', 'here', '!']
for item in listsItem:
    myQListWidget.addItem(item)
```

Another problem I found is that your search data are `QLineEdit`s , It isn’t a supported type in any overloaded method of `QListWidget.addItem()`. I think you can't pass it in to this method. But if you need the "text" in each `QLineEdit` only, you can convert it like this:

```py
self.studentAdmissionQGridLayout = QGridLayout()
.
.
.
self.myQListWidget = QListWidget()
listsMyQLineEdit = self.studentAdmissionQGridLayout.findChildren(QLineEdit)
for myQLineEdit in listsMyQLineEdit:
    self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQLineEdit.text())
```

Here is a reference to help to understand `QListWidget.addItem()`:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#addItem

Comment: on doing findChildren, the list that I am getting is empty,i.e.; listsMyQLineEdit  is empty.

Comment: Maybe you QLineEdit isn't set parent to QGridLayout. Then, is 'findChildren' method can't be solve problem.

Answer (score 4):

If the line-edits do not have the layout as parent, `findChildren` will not find them.

It may be better to iterate over the layout something like this:

```
for row in range(layout.rowCount()):
    for column in range(layout.columnCount()):
        item = layout.itemAtPosition(row, column)
        if item is not None:
            widget = item.widget()
            if isinstance(widget, QLineEdit):
                listWidget.addItem(widget.text())
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out about the parent, I rechecked, actually the QTabWidget was the parent here on which QGridLayout was placed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

So i ended up wanting to be able to loop through all the child objects from a uic module loaded and link them up dynamically and this loop may be of help for you with some slight mods for only the qlineedit ones

```
for name, obj in dict(self.__dict__).items():
        # print(str(name) + str(obj))
        obj_type = str(obj).strip("<PyQt5").rsplit(" ")[0].replace(".", '', 1)
        # obj_type = str(obj).strip("<").rsplit(" ")[0]
        # print(obj_type)
        # obj_type = obj_str.strip("<PyQt5").rsplit(" ")[0].replace(".", '', 1)
        label_name = "self." + str(name)
        try:
            label_name = self.findChild(eval(obj_type), name)
            print(str(label_name) + ' created')
        except:
            pass
        if not isinstance(obj_type, QObject):
            continue
```

The full code for stub i used to be able to load Qt Designer uic file and connect up custom slots and signals and live test is below

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

qtCreatorFile = "mainwindow.ui"  # Type your file path
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class build(Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        for name, obj in dict(self.__dict__).items():
            # print(str(name) + str(obj))
            obj_type = str(obj).strip("<PyQt5").rsplit(" ")[0].replace(".", '', 1)
            # obj_type = str(obj).strip("<").rsplit(" ")[0]
            # print(obj_type)
            # obj_type = obj_str.strip("<PyQt5").rsplit(" ")[0].replace(".", '', 1)
            label_name = "self." + str(name)
            try:
                label_name = self.findChild(eval(obj_type), name)
                print(str(label_name) + ' created')
            except:
                pass
            if not isinstance(obj_type, QObject):
                continue


def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    bld = build()
    bld.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```